# Getting error { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked." } from Google oauth2 API

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I created an app in my google developer console account back in 2016 & I have the client ID, client secret, access token & refresh token for this app. I'm trying to read the emails from my Gmail account using the google:mail API in my apache camel application. It was working fine till today & suddenly I am getting this error which says:

```
c.g.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential    : unable to refresh token

com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:362)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.handleResponse(Credential.java:272)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:999)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.component.google.mail.GoogleMailProducer.doInvokeMethod(GoogleMailProducer.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.util.component.AbstractApiProducer$1.run(AbstractApiProducer.java:86)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-07-20 11:31:02.689  WARN 20885 --- [CamelGoogleMail] o.a.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer  : Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-FVFXN5JKHV29-51050-1595224856126-0-2]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status" : "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}]
```

Is this because the access token or the refresh token has expired today after 2016? Should I try resetting the client secret from the google developer console?

EDIT - Here is the piece of code which I'm using

```
public GoogleMailComponent googleMailComponent() {
        GoogleMailConfiguration googleMailConfiguration = new GoogleMailConfiguration();
        googleMailConfiguration.setClientId(clientId);
        googleMailConfiguration.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        googleMailConfiguration.setAccessToken(accessToken);
        googleMailConfiguration.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

        GoogleMailComponent googleMailComponent = new GoogleMailComponent();
        googleMailComponent.setConfiguration(googleMailConfiguration);
        return googleMailComponent;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: And: Are you using a service account?

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka, I'm not using a service account I think. Can you please tell me where can I check that to be sure? Thanks!

Comment: I am asking because your error is common when using a service account, but probably you would know if you used one. See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for information about service accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting tokens/StoredCredential file allowed me to solve the issue.

Next time when I ran my Java application which was trying to connect to Google Sheets, it prompted me to

1. Go to a URL
2. Allow access to Google API

Comment: Hi, where is the token's folder? I can't find it on Windows.

Comment: I can't locate that application now. But think it was in the application's home directory. Have a look at this link where token folder is specified: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();

Comment: Yes, after writing the comment I was able to find it. Thanks anyway for your reply :)